# Wireless problems Lenovo Thinkpad E580

Tags: networking, thinkpad

I recently got a Thinkpad and installed Ubuntu 18.04.  I am having trouble connecting to wifi but ethernet works great.  I have looked around but have not found any solutions that work.

http://paste.ubuntu.com/p/rMGgVYYHG3/

```
########## wireless info START ##########

Report from: 05 Dec 2018 16:57 PST -0800

Booted last: 05 Dec 2018 00:00 PST -0800

Script from: 22 Oct 2018 03:34 UTC +0000

##### release ###########################

Distributor ID: Ubuntu
Description:    Ubuntu 18.04.1 LTS
Release:    18.04
Codename:   bionic

##### kernel ############################

Linux 4.15.0-42-generic #45-Ubuntu SMP Thu Nov 15 19:32:57 UTC 2018 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux

Parameters: ro, quiet, splash, vt.handoff=1

##### desktop ###########################

Ubuntu

##### lspci #############################

03:00.0 Ethernet controller [0200]: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd. RTL8111/8168/8411 PCI Express Gigabit Ethernet Controller [10ec:8168] (rev 10)
    Subsystem: Lenovo RTL8111/8168/8411 PCI Express Gigabit Ethernet Controller [17aa:5068]
    Kernel driver in use: r8169

05:00.0 Network controller [0280]: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd. Device [10ec:b822]
    Subsystem: Lenovo Device [17aa:b024]
    Kernel driver in use: r8822be

##### lsusb #############################

Bus 002 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0003 Linux Foundation 3.0 root hub
Bus 001 Device 004: ID 06cb:00a2 Synaptics, Inc. 
Bus 001 Device 003: ID 04f2:b604 Chicony Electronics Co., Ltd 
Bus 001 Device 005: ID 0bda:b023 Realtek Semiconductor Corp. 
Bus 001 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub

##### PCMCIA card info ##################

##### rfkill ############################

1: phy0: Wireless LAN
    Soft blocked: yes
    Hard blocked: no
2: tpacpi_bluetooth_sw: Bluetooth
    Soft blocked: yes
    Hard blocked: no
4: hci0: Bluetooth
    Soft blocked: no
    Hard blocked: no

##### secure boot #######################

SecureBoot disabled

##### lsmod #############################

rtl_pci                32768  0
rtlwifi                77824  2 rtl_pci,btcoexist
mac80211              778240  3 rtl_pci,rtlwifi,r8822be
cfg80211              622592  3 rtlwifi,mac80211,r8822be
wmi_bmof               16384  0
intel_wmi_thunderbolt    16384  0
wmi                    24576  2 intel_wmi_thunderbolt,wmi_bmof

##### interfaces ########################

[/etc/network/interfaces]
auto lo
iface lo inet loopback

##### ifconfig ##########################

1: lo:  mtu 65536 qdisc noqueue state UNKNOWN group default qlen 1000
    link/loopback  brd 
    inet 127.0.0.1/8 scope host lo
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
    inet6 ::1/128 scope host 
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
2: enp3s0:  mtu 1500 qdisc fq_codel state UP group default qlen 1000
    link/ether  brd 
    inet 192.168.1.23/24 brd 192.168.1.255 scope global dynamic noprefixroute enp3s0
       valid_lft 86038sec preferred_lft 86038sec
    inet6 fe80::5eb6:3bf7:e789:f962/64 scope link noprefixroute 
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
3: wlp5s0:  mtu 1500 qdisc noop state DOWN group default qlen 1000
    link/ether  brd 

##### iwconfig ##########################

lo        no wireless extensions.

enp3s0    no wireless extensions.

wlp5s0    IEEE 802.11  ESSID:off/any  
          Mode:Managed  Access Point: Not-Associated   Tx-Power=off   
          Retry short limit:7   RTS thr=2347 B   Fragment thr:off
          Power Management:on


##### route #############################

default via 192.168.1.1 dev enp3s0 proto dhcp metric 100 
169.254.0.0/16 dev enp3s0 scope link metric 1000 
192.168.1.0/24 dev enp3s0 proto kernel scope link src 192.168.1.23 metric 100 

##### resolv.conf #######################

[777 root '/etc/resolv.conf' -> '../run/systemd/resolve/stub-resolv.conf']

nameserver 127.0.0.53
search Home

##### network managers ##################

Installed:

    NetworkManager

Running:

root       785     1  0 16:16 ?        00:00:00 /usr/sbin/NetworkManager --no-daemon

##### NetworkManager info ###############

GENERAL.DEVICE:                         enp3s0
GENERAL.TYPE:                           ethernet
GENERAL.NM-TYPE:                        NMDeviceEthernet
GENERAL.VENDOR:                         Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd.
GENERAL.PRODUCT:                        RTL8111/8168/8411 PCI Express Gigabit Ethernet Controller
GENERAL.DRIVER:                         r8169
GENERAL.DRIVER-VERSION:                 2.3LK-NAPI
GENERAL.FIRMWARE-VERSION:               --
GENERAL.HWADDR:                         
GENERAL.MTU:                            1500
GENERAL.STATE:                          100 (connected)
GENERAL.REASON:                         0 (No reason given)
GENERAL.UDI:                            /sys/devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:1c.4/0000:03:00.0/net/enp3s0
GENERAL.IP-IFACE:                       enp3s0
GENERAL.IS-SOFTWARE:                    no
GENERAL.NM-MANAGED:                     yes
GENERAL.AUTOCONNECT:                    yes
GENERAL.FIRMWARE-MISSING:               no
GENERAL.NM-PLUGIN-MISSING:              no
GENERAL.PHYS-PORT-ID:                   --
GENERAL.CONNECTION:                     Wired connection 1
GENERAL.CON-UUID:                       8ba9a365-d4c1-3e09-8ccc-633c5c49df8c
GENERAL.CON-PATH:                       /org/freedesktop/NetworkManager/ActiveConnection/1
GENERAL.METERED:                        no (guessed)
CAPABILITIES.CARRIER-DETECT:            yes
CAPABILITIES.SPEED:                     100 Mb/s
CAPABILITIES.IS-SOFTWARE:               no
CAPABILITIES.SRIOV:                     no
WIRED-PROPERTIES.CARRIER:               on
IP4.ADDRESS[1]:                         192.168.1.23/24
IP4.GATEWAY:                            192.168.1.1
IP4.ROUTE[1]:                           dst = 0.0.0.0/0, nh = 192.168.1.1, mt = 100
IP4.ROUTE[2]:                           dst = 192.168.1.0/24, nh = 0.0.0.0, mt = 100
IP4.ROUTE[3]:                           dst = 169.254.0.0/16, nh = 0.0.0.0, mt = 1000
IP4.DNS[1]:                             192.168.1.1
IP4.DOMAIN[1]:                          Home
DHCP4.OPTION[1]:                        requested_host_name = 1
DHCP4.OPTION[2]:                        requested_domain_search = 1
DHCP4.OPTION[3]:                        network_number = 192.168.1.0
DHCP4.OPTION[4]:                        requested_time_offset = 1
DHCP4.OPTION[5]:                        requested_domain_name = 1
DHCP4.OPTION[6]:                        requested_rfc3442_classless_static_routes = 1
DHCP4.OPTION[7]:                        requested_broadcast_address = 1
DHCP4.OPTION[8]:                        domain_name = Home
DHCP4.OPTION[9]:                        requested_netbios_scope = 1
DHCP4.OPTION[10]:                       next_server = 0.0.0.0
DHCP4.OPTION[11]:                       broadcast_address = 192.168.1.255
DHCP4.OPTION[12]:                       requested_interface_mtu = 1
DHCP4.OPTION[13]:                       requested_subnet_mask = 1
DHCP4.OPTION[14]:                       dhcp_lease_time = 86400
DHCP4.OPTION[15]:                       dhcp_message_type = 5
DHCP4.OPTION[16]:                       ip_address = 192.168.1.23
DHCP4.OPTION[17]:                       subnet_mask = 255.255.255.0
DHCP4.OPTION[18]:                       requested_wpad = 1
DHCP4.OPTION[19]:                       routers = 192.168.1.1
DHCP4.OPTION[20]:                       requested_domain_name_servers = 1
DHCP4.OPTION[21]:                       requested_ntp_servers = 1
DHCP4.OPTION[22]:                       expiry = 1544143902
DHCP4.OPTION[23]:                       requested_netbios_name_servers = 1
DHCP4.OPTION[24]:                       requested_routers = 1
DHCP4.OPTION[25]:                       requested_ms_classless_static_routes = 1
DHCP4.OPTION[26]:                       requested_static_routes = 1
DHCP4.OPTION[27]:                       domain_name_servers = 192.168.1.1
DHCP4.OPTION[28]:                       dhcp_server_identifier = 192.168.1.1
IP6.ADDRESS[1]:                         fe80::5eb6:3bf7:e789:f962/64
IP6.GATEWAY:                            --
IP6.ROUTE[1]:                           dst = ff00::/8, nh = ::, mt = 256, table=255
IP6.ROUTE[2]:                           dst = fe80::/64, nh = ::, mt = 256
IP6.ROUTE[3]:                           dst = fe80::/64, nh = ::, mt = 100
CONNECTIONS.AVAILABLE-CONNECTION-PATHS: /org/freedesktop/NetworkManager/Settings/{7}
CONNECTIONS.AVAILABLE-CONNECTIONS[1]:   8ba9a365-d4c1-3e09-8ccc-633c5c49df8c | Wired connection 1

GENERAL.DEVICE:                         wlp5s0
GENERAL.TYPE:                           wifi
GENERAL.NM-TYPE:                        NMDeviceWifi
GENERAL.VENDOR:                         Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd.
GENERAL.PRODUCT:                        --
GENERAL.DRIVER:                         r8822be
GENERAL.DRIVER-VERSION:                 4.15.0-42-generic
GENERAL.FIRMWARE-VERSION:               N/A
GENERAL.HWADDR:                         
GENERAL.MTU:                            1500
GENERAL.STATE:                          20 (unavailable)
GENERAL.REASON:                         2 (Device is now managed)
GENERAL.UDI:                            /sys/devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:1d.2/0000:05:00.0/net/wlp5s0
GENERAL.IP-IFACE:                       --
GENERAL.IS-SOFTWARE:                    no
GENERAL.NM-MANAGED:                     yes
GENERAL.AUTOCONNECT:                    yes
GENERAL.FIRMWARE-MISSING:               no
GENERAL.NM-PLUGIN-MISSING:              no
GENERAL.PHYS-PORT-ID:                   --
GENERAL.CONNECTION:                     --
GENERAL.CON-UUID:                       --
GENERAL.CON-PATH:                       --
GENERAL.METERED:                        unknown
CAPABILITIES.CARRIER-DETECT:            no
CAPABILITIES.SPEED:                     unknown
CAPABILITIES.IS-SOFTWARE:               no
CAPABILITIES.SRIOV:                     no
WIFI-PROPERTIES.WEP:                    yes
WIFI-PROPERTIES.WPA:                    yes
WIFI-PROPERTIES.WPA2:                   yes
WIFI-PROPERTIES.TKIP:                   yes
WIFI-PROPERTIES.CCMP:                   yes
WIFI-PROPERTIES.AP:                     yes
WIFI-PROPERTIES.ADHOC:                  yes
WIFI-PROPERTIES.2GHZ:                   yes
WIFI-PROPERTIES.5GHZ:                   yes
CONNECTIONS.AVAILABLE-CONNECTION-PATHS: --

SSID  BSSID  MODE  CHAN  FREQ  RATE  SIGNAL  BARS  SECURITY  ACTIVE  IN-USE 

##### NetworkManager.state ##############

[main]
NetworkingEnabled=true
WirelessEnabled=false
WWANEnabled=true

##### NetworkManager config #############

[[/etc/NetworkManager/conf.d/default-wifi-powersave-on.conf]]
[connection]
wifi.powersave = 3

[[/etc/NetworkManager/NetworkManager.conf]]
[main]
plugins=ifupdown,keyfile
[ifupdown]
managed=false
[device]
wifi.scan-rand-mac-address=no

[[/usr/lib/NetworkManager/conf.d/10-dns-resolved.conf]]
[main]
dns=systemd-resolved

[[/usr/lib/NetworkManager/conf.d/10-globally-managed-devices.conf]]
[keyfile]
unmanaged-devices=*,except:type:wifi,except:type:wwan

[[/usr/lib/NetworkManager/conf.d/20-connectivity-ubuntu.conf]]
[connectivity]
uri=http://connectivity-check.ubuntu.com/

[[/usr/lib/NetworkManager/conf.d/no-mac-addr-change.conf]]
[device-mac-addr-change-wifi]
match-device=driver:rtl8723bs,driver:rtl8189es,driver:r8188eu,driver:8188eu,driver:eagle_sdio,driver:wl
wifi.scan-rand-mac-address=no
wifi.cloned-mac-address=preserve
ethernet.cloned-mac-address=preserve

##### NetworkManager profiles ###########

[[/etc/NetworkManager/system-connections/eduroam]] (600 root)
[connection] id=eduroam | type=wifi | permissions=
[wifi] mac-address= | mac-address-blacklist= | ssid=eduroam
[802-1x] ca-cert=/home/alec/Desktop/ca.der
[ipv4] method=auto
[ipv6] method=auto

[[/etc/NetworkManager/system-connections/Orca]] (600 root)
[connection] id=Orca | type=wifi | permissions=
[wifi] mac-address= | mac-address-blacklist= | ssid=Orca
[ipv4] method=auto
[ipv6] method=auto

[[/etc/NetworkManager/system-connections/UCSC-Guest]] (600 root)
[connection] id=UCSC-Guest | type=wifi | permissions=
[wifi] mac-address= | mac-address-blacklist= | ssid=UCSC-Guest
[ipv4] method=auto
[ipv6] method=auto

[[/etc/NetworkManager/system-connections/DIRECT-41-HP DeskJet 3700 series]] (600 root)
[connection] id=DIRECT-41-HP DeskJet 3700 series | type=wifi | permissions=
[wifi] mac-address= | mac-address-blacklist= | ssid=DIRECT-41-HP DeskJet 3700 series
[ipv4] method=auto
[ipv6] method=auto

[[/etc/NetworkManager/system-connections/Orca_5GEXT]] (600 root)
[connection] id=Orca_5GEXT | type=wifi | permissions=
[wifi] mac-address= | mac-address-blacklist= | ssid=Orca_5GEXT
[ipv4] method=auto
[ipv6] method=auto

[[/etc/NetworkManager/system-connections/iPhone]] (600 root)
[connection] id=iPhone | type=wifi | permissions=
[wifi] mac-address= | mac-address-blacklist= | ssid=iPhone
[ipv4] method=auto
[ipv6] method=auto

##### Netplan config ####################

[/etc/netplan/01-network-manager-all.yaml]
network:
  version: 2
  renderer: NetworkManager

##### iw reg get ########################

Region: America/Los_Angeles (based on set time zone)

global
country 00: DFS-UNSET
    (2402 - 2472 @ 40), (N/A, 20), (N/A)
    (2457 - 2482 @ 20), (N/A, 20), (N/A), AUTO-BW, PASSIVE-SCAN
    (2474 - 2494 @ 20), (N/A, 20), (N/A), NO-OFDM, PASSIVE-SCAN
    (5170 - 5250 @ 80), (N/A, 20), (N/A), AUTO-BW, PASSIVE-SCAN
    (5250 - 5330 @ 80), (N/A, 20), (0 ms), DFS, AUTO-BW, PASSIVE-SCAN
    (5490 - 5730 @ 160), (N/A, 20), (0 ms), DFS, PASSIVE-SCAN
    (5735 - 5835 @ 80), (N/A, 20), (N/A), PASSIVE-SCAN
    (57240 - 63720 @ 2160), (N/A, 0), (N/A)

##### iwlist channels ###################

lo        no frequency information.

enp3s0    no frequency information.

wlp5s0    32 channels in total; available frequencies :
          Channel 01 : 2.412 GHz
          Channel 02 : 2.417 GHz
          Channel 03 : 2.422 GHz
          Channel 04 : 2.427 GHz
          Channel 05 : 2.432 GHz
          Channel 06 : 2.437 GHz
          Channel 07 : 2.442 GHz
          Channel 08 : 2.447 GHz
          Channel 09 : 2.452 GHz
          Channel 10 : 2.457 GHz
          Channel 11 : 2.462 GHz
          Channel 12 : 2.467 GHz
          Channel 13 : 2.472 GHz
          Channel 36 : 5.18 GHz
          Channel 40 : 5.2 GHz
          Channel 44 : 5.22 GHz
          Channel 48 : 5.24 GHz
          Channel 52 : 5.26 GHz
          Channel 56 : 5.28 GHz
          Channel 60 : 5.3 GHz
          Channel 64 : 5.32 GHz
          Channel 100 : 5.5 GHz
          Channel 104 : 5.52 GHz
          Channel 108 : 5.54 GHz
          Channel 112 : 5.56 GHz
          Channel 116 : 5.58 GHz
          Channel 120 : 5.6 GHz
          Channel 124 : 5.62 GHz
          Channel 128 : 5.64 GHz
          Channel 132 : 5.66 GHz
          Channel 136 : 5.68 GHz
          Channel 140 : 5.7 GHz

##### iwlist scan #######################

lo        Interface doesn't support scanning.

enp3s0    Interface doesn't support scanning.

wlp5s0    Interface doesn't support scanning : Network is down

##### module infos ######################

[rtl_pci]
filename:       /lib/modules/4.15.0-42-generic/kernel/drivers/net/wireless/realtek/rtlwifi/rtl_pci.ko
description:    PCI basic driver for rtlwifi
license:        GPL
author:         Larry Finger    
author:         Realtek WlanFAE 
author:         lizhaoming  
srcversion:     D883A6C5A490FBE0CDF1B6A
depends:        mac80211,rtlwifi
retpoline:      Y
intree:         Y
name:           rtl_pci
vermagic:       4.15.0-42-generic SMP mod_unload 
signat:         PKCS#7
signer:         
sig_key:        
sig_hashalgo:   md4

[rtlwifi]
filename:       /lib/modules/4.15.0-42-generic/kernel/drivers/net/wireless/realtek/rtlwifi/rtlwifi.ko
description:    Realtek 802.11n PCI wireless core
license:        GPL
author:         Larry Finger    
author:         Realtek WlanFAE 
author:         lizhaoming  
srcversion:     12BDF0F9FFC2ACFD3465C5A
depends:        mac80211,cfg80211
retpoline:      Y
intree:         Y
name:           rtlwifi
vermagic:       4.15.0-42-generic SMP mod_unload 
signat:         PKCS#7
signer:         
sig_key:        
sig_hashalgo:   md4

[mac80211]
filename:       /lib/modules/4.15.0-42-generic/kernel/net/mac80211/mac80211.ko
license:        GPL
description:    IEEE 802.11 subsystem
srcversion:     10B87D6D65DDD085D1326C9
depends:        cfg80211
retpoline:      Y
intree:         Y
name:           mac80211
vermagic:       4.15.0-42-generic SMP mod_unload 
signat:         PKCS#7
signer:         
sig_key:        
sig_hashalgo:   md4
parm:           minstrel_vht_only:Use only VHT rates when VHT is supported by sta. (bool)
parm:           max_nullfunc_tries:Maximum nullfunc tx tries before disconnecting (reason 4). (int)
parm:           max_probe_tries:Maximum probe tries before disconnecting (reason 4). (int)
parm:           beacon_loss_count:Number of beacon intervals before we decide beacon was lost. (int)
parm:           probe_wait_ms:Maximum time(ms) to wait for probe response before disconnecting (reason 4). (int)
parm:           ieee80211_default_rc_algo:Default rate control algorithm for mac80211 to use (charp)

[cfg80211]
filename:       /lib/modules/4.15.0-42-generic/kernel/net/wireless/cfg80211.ko
description:    wireless configuration support
license:        GPL
author:         Johannes Berg
srcversion:     62FD05DCC5AEEA290640C3D
depends:        
retpoline:      Y
intree:         Y
name:           cfg80211
vermagic:       4.15.0-42-generic SMP mod_unload 
signat:         PKCS#7
signer:         
sig_key:        
sig_hashalgo:   md4
parm:           bss_entries_limit:limit to number of scan BSS entries (per wiphy, default 1000) (int)
parm:           ieee80211_regdom:IEEE 802.11 regulatory domain code (charp)
parm:           cfg80211_disable_40mhz_24ghz:Disable 40MHz support in the 2.4GHz band (bool)

##### module parameters #################

[mac80211]
beacon_loss_count: 7
ieee80211_default_rc_algo: minstrel_ht
max_nullfunc_tries: 2
max_probe_tries: 5
minstrel_vht_only: Y
probe_wait_ms: 500

[cfg80211]
bss_entries_limit: 1000
cfg80211_disable_40mhz_24ghz: N
ieee80211_regdom: 00

##### /etc/modules ######################

##### modprobe options ##################

[/etc/modprobe.d/amd64-microcode-blacklist.conf]
blacklist microcode

[/etc/modprobe.d/blacklist-ath_pci.conf]
blacklist ath_pci

[/etc/modprobe.d/blacklist.conf]
blacklist evbug
blacklist usbmouse
blacklist usbkbd
blacklist eepro100
blacklist de4x5
blacklist eth1394
blacklist snd_intel8x0m
blacklist snd_aw2
blacklist prism54
blacklist bcm43xx
blacklist garmin_gps
blacklist asus_acpi
blacklist snd_pcsp
blacklist pcspkr
blacklist amd76x_edac

[/etc/modprobe.d/blacklist-rare-network.conf]
alias net-pf-3 off
alias net-pf-6 off
alias net-pf-9 off
alias net-pf-11 off
alias net-pf-12 off
alias net-pf-19 off
alias net-pf-21 off
alias net-pf-36 off

[/etc/modprobe.d/intel-microcode-blacklist.conf]
blacklist microcode

[/etc/modprobe.d/iwlwifi.conf]
remove iwlwifi \
(/sbin/lsmod | grep -o -e ^iwlmvm -e ^iwldvm -e ^iwlwifi | xargs /sbin/rmmod) \
&& /sbin/modprobe -r mac80211

[/etc/modprobe.d/r8822be.conf]
options r8822be aspm=0

[/etc/modprobe.d/rtl8822be.conf]
options rtl8822be fwlps=0

##### rc.local ##########################

grep: /etc/rc.local: No such file or directory

##### pm-utils ##########################

##### udev rules ########################

##### dmesg #############################

[   14.475967] Bluetooth: hci0: rtl: examining hci_ver=07 hci_rev=000b lmp_ver=07 lmp_subver=8822
[   14.475982] Bluetooth: hci0: rtl: loading rtl_bt/rtl8822b_config.bin
[   14.476163] Bluetooth: hci0: rtl: loading rtl_bt/rtl8822b_fw.bin
[  137.598486] r8822be: rtlwifi: wireless switch is on
[  137.646691] r8169 0000:03:00.0 enp3s0: link down
[  138.828323] Bluetooth: hci0: rtl: examining hci_ver=07 hci_rev=000b lmp_ver=07 lmp_subver=8822
[  138.828330] Bluetooth: hci0: rtl: loading rtl_bt/rtl8822b_config.bin
[  138.828354] Bluetooth: hci0: rtl: loading rtl_bt/rtl8822b_fw.bin
[  139.066312] IPv6: ADDRCONF(NETDEV_UP): enp3s0: link is not ready
[  139.110259] r8169 0000:03:00.0 enp3s0: link down
[  139.110318] IPv6: ADDRCONF(NETDEV_UP): enp3s0: link is not ready
[  139.110937] IPv6: ADDRCONF(NETDEV_UP): wlp5s0: link is not ready
[  141.489614] r8169 0000:03:00.0 enp3s0: link up
[  141.489634] IPv6: ADDRCONF(NETDEV_CHANGE): enp3s0: link becomes ready

########## wireless info END ############
```

Answer (score 0):

In your paste results we see this:

```
1: phy0: Wireless LAN
   Soft blocked: yes
   Hard blocked: no
```

In this context, ‘soft blocked’ implies that the wireless is disabled by software, not by the physical switch. This is confirmed further in your paste:

```
##### NetworkManager.state ##############

[main]
NetworkingEnabled=true
WirelessEnabled=false   ←-- should read =true
WWANEnabled=true
```

Please select Settings > WiFi and check that the Airplane Mode button is turned on. If so, please tick it off.

[image]

**EDIT**: In your second paste, we see:

> authentication with 'Orca_5GEXT' timed out

We see, in the list of access points:

> Orca_5GEXT    Infra  153   5765 MHz  135
>   Mbit/s  59      ▂▄▆_  WPA1 WPA2  no

The desired access point is set to use channel 153.

Your wireless card reports this:

```
<snip>
      Channel 112 : 5.56 GHz
      Channel 116 : 5.58 GHz
      Channel 120 : 5.6 GHz
      Channel 124 : 5.62 GHz
      Channel 128 : 5.64 GHz
      Channel 132 : 5.66 GHz
      Channel 136 : 5.68 GHz
      Channel 140 : 5.7 GHz
```

In other words, the highest channel your wireless device reports as available is 140. The desired access point  Orca_5GEXT is set to channel 153.

Please change the settings in the router to use a fixed, not auto-select, channel in the range that your wireless card reports; for example, 132 or 136 or 140.

I also note that Orca_5GEXT is set to mixed mode WPA and WPA2. WPA2-AES is preferred; not any WPA and WPA2 mixed mode and certainly not TKIP.

**EDIT 2**: It is possible that you may expose more channels by properly setting your regulatory domain. Check yours:

```
sudo iw reg get
```

If you get 00, that is a one-size-maybe-fits-all setting. Find yours here: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_3166-1_alpha-2 Then set it temporarily:

```
sudo iw reg set IS
```

Of course, substitute your country code if not Iceland. Set it permanently:

```
sudo nano /etc/default/crda
```

Change the last line to read:

```
REGDOMAIN=IS
```

Proofread carefully, save and close the text editor. Reboot and check:

```
sudo iwlist chan
```

Now are channels above 140 available? Can you now connect?

Comment: Thanks for your reply.  I saw that airplane mode was not on.  I toggled it on and then off again but still can not connect to wifi. However now when I type rfkill list all I see 2: phy0: Wireless LAN
 Soft blocked: no
 Hard blocked: no

Comment: May we see a new paste, please? http://paste.ubuntu.com

Comment: Of course.  http://paste.ubuntu.com/p/WgXWhQfW9p/

Comment: It clearly says: "Soft blocked: yes" and: "WirelessEnabled=false"  Please check Airplane Mode again.

Comment: Apologies, I had wifi off while I ran the script.  Here is the script with wifi on http://paste.ubuntu.com/p/KNr9XHdPWw/

Comment: Please see my edit above in a few moments.

Comment: I am a renter and can not necessarily change router settings, is there any way around this?  I also need to access wifi in public places such as university and coffee shops which I have trouble with as well.  I was able to connect briefly at university today but it stopped working in 15 minutes.  Here is a paste at university http://paste.ubuntu.com/p/DqYjCgV4Vg/

Comment: Please see my edit above in a few moments. This is purely experimental.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/86777/discussion-between-amd-and-chili555).